# How to make KVM guest configs persistent across reboots/shutdown

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

I create a KVM Guest VM (virsh define a.xml, virsh start a.xml). Guest uses pre-configured/pre-made QCOW2 disk image, which represents a virtual router (Arista vEOS). Host is Redhat 9.1. Guest is based on Centos 7.9. The VM uses a boot loader (Aboot) in a cdrom.
The guest has two environments where one can configure it: **Bash Shell** as well as "**Arista CLI**".

I use bash to make changes to the system: adduser; add,partition,format,mount disk; install libraries (gcc, glibc ...etc) .... Problem is, I lose all of these config changes when I do "**shutdown**" via bash from within the guest or when I do "**virsh shutdown guest**" from the kvm host.

How do I make these extra configurations persistent even after shutting down the guest?

I wonder if these configs have something to do with it: `<on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff> ,,, <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot> ,,, <on_crash>restart</on_crash>`

Comment: This problem is not related to virtualization, and is a side-effect of how the operating system is handling initialization (it's likely using a read-only image for root and persisting changes in memory only). You should ask this question in the specific context of vEOS. In general, you'll have to attach a second disk and mount it during or after boot. I don't know the specifics of vEOS.